# JSONObject not found

Tags: java, json, jsonobject

Estoy llamando a una api a través del siguiente código,

```
 public static String consultarPago(String idpago) throws MalformedURLException {
        StringBuilder respuesta = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject json = null;

        String ULRredirec = null;
        String complement = "transactions?reference=";
        try {
            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            URL object = new URL(URL_WOMPI + complement + idpago);
            // Abrir la conexión e indicar que será de tipo GET
            con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + PRV_WOMPI);
            boolean encontrado = false;

            while (encontrado == false) {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {

                    String acumuladorRespuesta = null;
                    while ((acumuladorRespuesta = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        respuesta.append(acumuladorRespuesta.trim());
                        if (respuesta != null) {
                            json = new JSONObject(respuesta.toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            
                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                ULRredirec = jsonObject.getJSONObject("payment_method").getJSONObject("extra").getString("async_payment_url");
                                encontrado = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error URL Redirec" + e);
        }
        return ULRredirec;
    }
```

donde responde con la siguiente salida Json.

```
{
    "payment_method_type": "PSE",
    "status_message": null,
    "payment_source_id": null,
    "payment_link_id": null,
    "created_at": "2021-04-06T16:27:14.198Z",
    "reference": "15.23591119754338",
    "amount_in_cents": 2000000,
    "customer_email": "savera28@misena.edu.co",
    "customer_data": {
        "full_name": "Sergio Vera"
    },
    "currency": "COP",
    "id": "166561-1617726434-42579",
    "shipping_address": null,
    "payment_method": {
        "user_legal_id": "1018510220",
        "user_type": 0,
        "financial_institution_code": "1507",
        "user_legal_id_type": "CC",
        "payment_description": "Producto de CARWAY",
        "type": "PSE"
    },
    "redirect_url": "https://carwaystore.com/Store/",
    "status": "PENDING"
}
```

pero me sale el siguiente error

json.JSONException: JSONObject["extra"] not found.

Me di cuenta que al momento de hacer debug me responde con otro json que es el siguiente:

```
{
    "payment_method_type": "PSE",
    "status_message": null,
    "payment_source_id": null,
    "payment_link_id": null,
    "created_at": "2021-04-06T16:46:53.325Z",
    "reference": "7.291314793672276",
    "amount_in_cents": 2000000,
    "customer_email": "Armandosveras258sss@gmail.com",
    "customer_data": {
        "full_name": "Sergio Vera"
    },
    "currency": "COP",
    "id": "166561-1617727613-57504",
    "shipping_address": null,
    "payment_method": {
        "user_legal_id": "1018510998",
        "user_type": 0,
        "financial_institution_code": "1032",
        "user_legal_id_type": "CC",
        "payment_description": "Producto de CARWAY",
        "extra": {
            "async_payment_url": "https://registro.pse.com.co/PSEUserRegister/StartTransaction.htm?enc=tnPcJHMKlSnmRpHM8fAbu6kv8TPLHnynXFoiWYjfe5RR7kzPUcGcNxZWrD%2bMYgeA",
            "external_identifier": "946329192",
            "traceability_code": "946329192",
            "return_code": "SUCCESS",
            "transaction_cycle": "3"
        },
        "type": "PSE"
    },
    "redirect_url": "https://carwaystore.com/Store/",
    "status": "PENDING"
}
```

En el segundo json podemos ver que si me trae el objeto "extra"
pero solo trae el objeto "extra" si hago debug. de lo contrario me trae el primer json.
en pocas palabras solo funciona si hago debug.
¿como puedo solucionar ese error?

gracias de antemano.

Comment: No veo ningún `JSONArray`, entonces, ¿por qué usas `JSONArray` en tu código? Luego, en uno de los `payment_method`  la propiedad `extra`  no existe. Si los JSON no tienen la misma estructura debes preguntar por la propiedad en vez de pasar a leerla sin más.

Comment: Si la propiedad solo existe en modo debug, y en producción no usas el modo debug... no hay nada que puedas hacer para solucionarlo. El dueño de la API elige lo que devuelve en cada caso.

Answer (score -1):

Pasa que estas entrando en anidaciones, debes de separar los objetos.

```
JSONObject paymentMethod = jsonObject.getJSONObject("payment_method");
JSONObject extra = paymentMethod.getJSONObject("extra");
ULRredirec = extra.getString("async_payment_url");
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: No le va a funcionar, y no es cuestión de anidaciones. Es simplemente que la API que está atacando solo devuelve `extra` cuando se ataca en modo debug. Si te fijas, en la primera estructura que recibe no existe el atributo `extra`.